# airwatch pushed .pfx certificate not visible while setting up native email

Tags: android, email, client-certificates, airwatch

I am using an LG G3 smartphone running Android 5.0.

Now my company introduced airwatch and pushed the certificates down to my mobile device. Using the airwatch agent app I can see the CA certificates as well as my .pfx certificate.

When I now try to setup my native email client (Microsoft Exchange) there is no client certificate shown which I can select.

When now trying to connect to the server I get the notification:

```
Unable to open connection to server due to security
```

I guess this is due to the missing client certificate. Any idea what might went wrong or what I could check?

Comment: Do your company plan to configure Exchange through AirWatch?

Comment: I don't think so, main purpose is to have access to the phone in case it gets stolen or lost as far as I understand.